# Вывести первый элемент массива по наибольшему значению совпадений

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив

```
$feedbacks = [
    ['id' => 1023, 'user_id'=> 44393, 'msg'=> 'Comment 1', 'rate' => 5 ],
    ['id' => 1024, 'user_id'=> 22341, 'msg'=> 'Comment 2', 'rate' => 4 ],
    ['id' => 1025, 'user_id'=> 22341, 'msg'=> 'Comment 3', 'rate' => 4 ],
    ['id' => 1026, 'user_id'=> 44393, 'msg'=> 'Comment 4', 'rate' => 2 ],
    ['id' => 1027, 'user_id'=> 22341, 'msg'=> 'Comment 5', 'rate' => 3 ],
    ['id' => 1028, 'user_id'=> 75874, 'msg'=> 'Comment 6', 'rate' => 5 ],
    ['id' => 1029, 'user_id'=> 11223, 'msg'=> 'Comment 7', 'rate' => 1 ],
    ['id' => 1030, 'user_id'=> 44421, 'msg'=> 'Comment 8', 'rate' => 4 ],
]
```

Необходимо вывести того, кто больше всех комментариев оставил.

```
usort($feedbacks, "sorting");

function sorting($a, $b) {
     return $a['user_id'] == $b['user_id'];
}
```

Но тут первым выходит пользователь 44393, а нужен 22341 потому что кол вхождений 3 а у 44393 - 2

Comment: потому что сортировку пишут не так?

Comment: Не понимаю как отсортировать

Comment: хотел без цикла попробовать. Потому что с циклом ужас получается

Comment: В итоге непонятно по чему сортировать и причём тут количество вхождений

Comment: Я просто думал через сортировку найти user_id, который больше всех комментировал. Думал, что если через сортировку будет легче это сделать.

Comment: А откуда вы эти данные изначально получаете, может отсортировать на стороне SQL, если из реляционной БД ? Или вам надо сначала пройтись по массиву и посчитать вхождения (в отдельном массиве, адресуемом по user_id) и сортировать уже исходя из значений в нем

Comment: @nightwolf посмотрите на результат этого примера: [Демо](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d9a2e795db02d0776e50b7effaefd28fd901f74c)

Comment: @Mike нет это не из запроса. Это апиха и через file_get_contents получаю данные

Comment: ну значит вторым написанным мной методом, посчитав вхождения заранее.

Comment: Вообще мне посути только user_id нужен

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот так можно, если айдишник. Немного магии:

```
$users = array_count_values(array_column($feedbacks, 'user_id'));
  asort($users);
  end( $users); 
  echo(key($users));
```

Answer (score 3):

> Добавлю вариант для версии PHP <= 5.4:

```
$feedbacks = [
    ['id' => 1023, 'user_id'=> 44393, 'msg'=> 'Comment 1', 'rate' => 5 ],
    ['id' => 1024, 'user_id'=> 22341, 'msg'=> 'Comment 2', 'rate' => 4 ],
    ['id' => 1025, 'user_id'=> 22341, 'msg'=> 'Comment 3', 'rate' => 4 ],
    ['id' => 1026, 'user_id'=> 44393, 'msg'=> 'Comment 4', 'rate' => 2 ],
    ['id' => 1027, 'user_id'=> 22341, 'msg'=> 'Comment 5', 'rate' => 3 ],
    ['id' => 1028, 'user_id'=> 75874, 'msg'=> 'Comment 6', 'rate' => 5 ],
    ['id' => 1029, 'user_id'=> 11223, 'msg'=> 'Comment 7', 'rate' => 1 ],
    ['id' => 1030, 'user_id'=> 44421, 'msg'=> 'Comment 8', 'rate' => 4 ]
];

array_walk_recursive($feedbacks, function($v, $k) use(&$user_id) {
    $k != 'user_id' ?: $user_id[] = $v;
});
$user_id = array_count_values($user_id);
echo array_flip($user_id)[max($user_id)]; // 22341
```

> [Просмотр](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/08e6eccf266ffdbc51da83893d803a99e6533d2d)